# Making CreateProcess inherit the console of the calling process

Tags: windows, console, createprocess

When I call CreateProcess in Windows, the new process doesn't seem to inherit the console of the calling process.  I made a test program that runs "ruby xtest", xtest being a script that writes "hello" to standard output.  I ran this test program from Emacs, and get no output.  I also tried the following code calling GetStdHandle, but again, no output.  Then I tried passing CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE in dwCreationFlags to CreateProcess, which made a whole new window with the Ruby output.  Finally, I made a simple fork/exec
test program and compiled it using Cygwin's GCC.  This program worked: the Ruby output showed up in Emacs as expected.  I tried to decipher the Cygwin source code in http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/winsup/cygwin/spawn.cc?rev=1.268&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src but failed.  So, how do you make the new process inherit the console of the parent process such that the output from the child shows up as expected?

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
si.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
si.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
if(!CreateProcess(0, "ruby xtest", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi)) die("CreateProcess");
```

Comment: What I found working best is the undocumented value of 0 for the creation flags, just like in the example given. Worked as expected when compiled for Windows 7 (in non-UNICODE mode) by both VS 2019 and MSYS2/MinGW's gcc 9.1. So, if the example failed ~11 years ago, it could've been due to the WIn32 API behaving differently for this undocumented case.

Answer (score 9):

I know, this thread is rather old, however, I just ran into the same problem.

Just as for the TS, the console handle was inherited and working fine under Cygwin, but not on a Windows console. Instead, the output on stdout was neither shown, nor any error was reported. Inherited Pipe handles worked still fine.

I took me some time to identify the (now obvious) problem: CreateProcess() was called with CREATE_NO_WINDOW. Dropping this flag, console output is fine. (Though, according to the code of the TS, they never set this flag in the first place.)

Hope this might be helpful for people who also stumble across this thread, like myself.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has saved me soooooo much time and trouble!

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft documentation, *lpCommandLine* (2. parameter):

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

When I stopped using a constant here it worked for me. I didn't need the STARTF_USESTDHANDLES and GetStdHandle thing.

This code from a console prg runs and outputs another console exe in the same console:

```
FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
SI.cb:=SizeOf(SI);
FillChar(PI, SizeOf(PI), 0);
if CreateProcess(nil, CmdLineVar, nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI) then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by passing in pipes for `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, and `hStdError` and manually routing data from the `hStdOutput` and `hStdError` pipes to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if debeige ever solved this, but I needed the same thing, but starting up another thread to listen to stdout output, just to put it on stdout seemed nuts to me.

The following works for me, and is slightly different than what he originally posted.  I thought at first it wouldn't work if you don't set si.cb, but when I commented that in mine, it still worked, so... YMMV.

```
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
   siStartInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
   siStartInfo.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
   siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;  // my outgoing pipe
   siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// Create the child process. 

   bSuccess = CreateProcess(
      NULL,         
      szCmdline,    
      NULL,         
      NULL,         
      TRUE,         
      0,            
      NULL,         
      NULL,         
      &siStartInfo, 
      &piProcInfo);
```