# Using Delphi's ShellExecute() with the process inheriting the original console?

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

In C I've used the `system()` function before in a console application and if I start another process using `system()` it inherits the console window of the process that called it.

In Delphi `system()` doesn't exist so I'm using `ShellExecute()` to create a new process, but the new process comes up in a new console window.  Is there some way that I can make it inherit the handle of the window that's calling it?

I've used

```
function GetConsoleWindow(): HWND; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
```

to get the console window and passed it in the `HWND` part of `ShellExecute()`, but that didn't work.

Comment: I for to say I've used:
function GetConsoleWindow():HWND; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
This function to get the console window in an attempt to pass that in the HWID part of ShellExecute, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've added that to your question, hopefully in the way you meant it.

Comment: Phil, when you say "it didn't work," what do you mean by that?  What did it do instead?

Comment: It opens another console window.

Answer (score 5):

Using `ShellExecute()` you won't be able to make the spawned application use the same console. The `HWND` element in the `ShellExecute()` call is documented:

> Specifies a parent window. This window receives any message boxes that an application produces. For example, an application may report an error by producing a message box.

so it won't have any effect for console applications.

If you use [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead you have much more control over the spawned process. By using the [`dwCreationFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) parameter you can force the new process to get its own console (use the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag), but per default it will inherit the console of the parent process as well.

Comment: Great, I'm going to try that out.
If it helps anybody I actually found a similar article.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340356/making-createprocess-inherit-the-console-of-the-calling-process