# How do I correctly launch a process and forward stdin/stdout/stderr?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pipe, createprocess

I'm using `CreateProcess` to launch an interactive script interpreter and would like to transparently forward stdin/stdout/stderr from/to the interpreter.

My first attempt was to setup the `STARTUPINFO` structure passed to `CreateProcess` like

```
STARTUPINFOA si = { sizeof( si ) };
si.hStdError = ::GetStdHandle( STD_ERROR_HANDLE );
si.hStdOutput = ::GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
si.hStdInput = ::GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
```

I.e. I tried to make the script interpreter process use the very same handle for reading/writing as my launcher process uses. That didn't seem to work though (I'm not even sure those standard handles can be inherited).

A second idea, based on the [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example is to setup three pipes to forward all data written to any of the pipes. Since I don't know how to wait for data to be written to more than one file (`WaitForMultipleObjects` cannot synchronize on pipes), I was considering to have three threads, each of which doing a blocking `ReadFile` call on a pipe.

I suspect that this might be overkill though so I'm wondering: is there some easier way to do this? I don't need to do any kind of processing of the data passed from/to the script interpreter at all.

As a side note, on Linux I'm using `execvp` to just replace the current process with the script interpreter process, but on Windows I need to launch the script interpreter with the main thread in suspended state (so that I can do some bytecode patching) - so even since _execvp seems to be availble on Windows, I apparantly have to use CreateProcess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making CreateProcess inherit the console of the calling process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340356/making-createprocess-inherit-the-console-of-the-calling-process)

Comment: Re: how to wait for I/O on more than one file. You create one `OVERLAPPED` structure, complete with an event handle, for each file handle, and issue asynchronous I/O requests (e.g. `ReadFile`) passing those `OVERLAPPED` structures in. Then wait on those event handles.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that in an answer, @Igor? That seems to be the primary difference from [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485923/launch-an-exe-process-with-stdin-stdout-and-stderr) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340356/making-createprocess-inherit-the-console-of-the-calling-process) here.

Comment: @Shog9: OK, I posted something. Not sure if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks @Igor - that'll do it. FWIW, I've always just used (blocked) background threads for this, but there are good reasons to avoid that in some cases - note also that waitformultipleobjectsex can be used to integrate this with UI updates in a GUI app.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340356/making-createprocess-inherit-the-console-of-the-calling-process

Comment: I do wonder whether passing the standard handles explicitely via `STARTUPINFO` is really necessary. What handles does the child process get if you don't pass any handles (and don't use the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popuplating the `STARTUPINFO` as shown by the OP works fine *if* you make sure to not pass the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` argument in the `dwFlags` argument of [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

In order to wait for I/O on more than one file or pipe, you issue asynchronous I/O requests on each of those files, then wait for completion of said requests. Something along these lines (untested):

```
HANDLE file1, file2; // initialized somehow

HANDLE events[2];
events[0] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
events[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

OVERLAPPED overlapped1 = {0};
overlapped1.hEvent = events[0];
OVERLAPPED overlapped2 = {0};
overlapped2.hEvent = events[1];

ReadFile(file1, buffer1, size1, NULL, &overlapped1);
ReadFile(file2, buffer2, size2, NULL, &overlapped2);

WaitForMultipleObjects(2, events, FALSE, INFINITE);
```

`ReadFile` and `WaitForMultipleObjects` would need to be called in a loop. You check the return value of `WaitForMultipleObjects` to know which operation has completed, use `GetOverlappedResult` to discover the outcome of that operation (whether it succeeded, and if so, how many bytes it retrieved), process the data, call `ReadFile` for that handle again if you want to read some more from it, then get back to waiting. This is somewhat similar to a loop of non-blocking I/O driven by `select` in Linux.

Still more advanced technique is [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx). This allows one to have a thread pool handling lots of asynchronous I/O. Commonly used in Web servers and such, probably overkill for your case.